# SQL Server : prevent lock of the table during inserts in a loop

Tags: sql-server, transactions, cursor, locking

I have a transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

OPEN cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BigTable () VALUES ()
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @i
END

COMMIT;
```

The problem is, that transaction locks `BigTable` for the whole loop and `WAITFOR DELAY` time.

How to prevent locking it, that the table will be locked only during `INSERT`s?

Comment: SQL Server will use **row-level** locking - unless you update / insert / delete more than 5000 rows in a single transaction - then it'll do a **lock escalation** and lock the entire table. So the solution is: don't manipulate more than 5000 rows at once - do them in batches of less than 5000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> transaction locks table

The transaction does not lock the **table**, it locks the rows inserted. And the locks are held until the end of transaction, this is non-negotiable.

A much better question would be 'how can I read the data during the inserts?' and the answer is, of course, to use [snapshot isolation](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) in your **readers**.

Answer (score 1):

Please add "FOR  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY" fro cursor:

```
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
SELECT columnname...
FROM table-name

BEGIN TRANSACTION

OPEN cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BigTable () VALUES ()
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @i
END

COMMIT;
```